# In the Xcode editor how do you list variable names to the structure as you type?

Tags: iphone, xcode, editor

In the Xcode editor, how do you set it up to see the structure variable list as you type the structure name and then the "." ??

In Visual C++ I can see the variable list after I hit the "." to any structure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're talking about CodeSense. To get that window to pop up, all you need to do is hit the escape key. When you do this in the context of an object reference, you'll see all of the available fields/methods for that object.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking exactly but try to show stuff:

```
ctrl+space
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Good short cut to look things up.